# Set, HashSet и for each цикл

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, и не могли бы Вы мне объяснить, почему в примере ниже тип Stribg требует заменить Objeсt-ом?  Ведь при добавлении явно видно, что мы вносим в массив строку.

```
    Set set = new HashSet();
    set.add("Mama");
    set.add("Mila");
    set.add("Ramu");

    for (String text : set)
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Comment: для сета не указан тип данных. Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(). По умолчанию тип данных Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цитирую
@Okdel : *для сета не указан тип данных. Set set = new HashSet(). По умолчанию тип данных Object*

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("Mama");
set.add("Mila");
set.add("Ramu");

for (String text : set)
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
```